# Can't Compile .ino using ArduinoJson Library

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, c, esp32, json

I am using an ESP32 NodeMCU for which I wrote working software before. This also occurs when I just try to compile without uploading, so no hardware problem.
I am using the newest version of **ArduinoJson(6.12.0)** and it is included:

`#include <ArduinoJson.h>`

The only Function where I use the Library (I'm not good at C/C++, so maybe there is an error):

```
int DeserializeJson(char *json, int *pin, int *pinmode, int *timeInMilliseconds){

  StaticJsonDocument<1024> doc;                       
  DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc,json); 

  if (error) {  

    Serial.println("Parsing failed");
    return -1;
  }

  memcpy(&pin, doc["Pin"], sizeof( doc["Pin"]));
  memcpy(&pinmode, doc["Mode"], sizeof( doc["Mode"]));
  memcpy(&timeInMilliseconds, doc["TimeInMilliseconds"], sizeof( doc["TimeInMilliseconds"]));

  return 0;
}
```

This is the error I'm getting (at least a part of it):

```
In file included from C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Array/ArrayIterator.hpp:8:0,

                 from C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Array/ArrayRef.hpp:8,

                 from C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson.hpp:17,

                 from C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson.h:9,

                 from C:\Users\error404\source\repos\IOT\esp32\esp32.ino:1:

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantRef.hpp: In instantiation of 'typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::enable_if<(((! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ArrayRef>::value) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ObjectRef>::value)) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantRef>::value)), typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantAs<T>::type>::type ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantRef::as() const [with T = const void*; typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::enable_if<(((! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ArrayRef>::value) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ObjectRef>::value)) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantRef>::value)), typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantAs<T>::type>::type = const void*]':

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Object/MemberProxy.hpp:70:52:   required from 'typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantAs<T>::type ArduinoJson6120_000001::MemberProxy<TParent, TStringRef>::as() const [with TValue = const void*; TObject = ArduinoJson6120_000001::JsonDocument&; TStringRef = const char*; typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantAs<T>::type = const void*]'

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Operators/VariantCasts.hpp:16:35:   required from 'ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantCasts<TImpl>::operator T() const [with T = const void*; TImpl = ArduinoJson6120_000001::MemberProxy<ArduinoJson6120_000001::JsonDocument&, const char*>]'

C:\Users\error404\source\repos\IOT\esp32\esp32.ino:70:47:   required from here

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantRef.hpp:240:24: error: no matching function for call to 'variantAs(ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantData* const&)'

     return variantAs<T>(_data);

                        ^

In file included from C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Operators/VariantOr.hpp:9:0,

                 from C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Operators/VariantOperators.hpp:9,

                 from C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantRef.hpp:12,

                 from C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Array/ArrayIterator.hpp:8,

                 from C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Array/ArrayRef.hpp:8,

                 from C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson.hpp:17,

                 from C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson.h:9,

                 from C:\Users\error404\source\repos\IOT\esp32\esp32.ino:1:

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantAs.hpp:55:59: note: candidate: template<class T> typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::enable_if<ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type ArduinoJson6120_000001::variantAs(const ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantData*)

 inline typename enable_if<is_integral<T>::value, T>::type variantAs(

                                                           ^

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantAs.hpp:55:59: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantAs.hpp: In substitution of 'template<class T> typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::enable_if<ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type ArduinoJson6120_000001::variantAs(const ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantData*) [with T = const void*]':

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantRef.hpp:240:24:   required from 'typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::enable_if<(((! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ArrayRef>::value) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ObjectRef>::value)) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantRef>::value)), typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantAs<T>::type>::type ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantRef::as() const [with T = const void*; typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::enable_if<(((! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ArrayRef>::value) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ObjectRef>::value)) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantRef>::value)), typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantAs<T>::type>::type = const void*]'

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Object/MemberProxy.hpp:70:52:   required from 'typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantAs<T>::type ArduinoJson6120_000001::MemberProxy<TParent, TStringRef>::as() const [with TValue = const void*; TObject = ArduinoJson6120_000001::JsonDocument&; TStringRef = const char*; typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantAs<T>::type = const void*]'

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Operators/VariantCasts.hpp:16:35:   required from 'ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantCasts<TImpl>::operator T() const [with T = const void*; TImpl = ArduinoJson6120_000001::MemberProxy<ArduinoJson6120_000001::JsonDocument&, const char*>]'

C:\Users\error404\source\repos\IOT\esp32\esp32.ino:70:47:   required from here

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantAs.hpp:55:59: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct ArduinoJson6120_000001::enable_if<false, const void*>'

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantRef.hpp: In instantiation of 'typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::enable_if<(((! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ArrayRef>::value) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ObjectRef>::value)) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantRef>::value)), typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantAs<T>::type>::type ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantRef::as() const [with T = const void*; typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::enable_if<(((! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ArrayRef>::value) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ObjectRef>::value)) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantRef>::value)), typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantAs<T>::type>::type = const void*]':

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Object/MemberProxy.hpp:70:52:   required from 'typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantAs<T>::type ArduinoJson6120_000001::MemberProxy<TParent, TStringRef>::as() const [with TValue = const void*; TObject = ArduinoJson6120_000001::JsonDocument&; TStringRef = const char*; typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantAs<T>::type = const void*]'

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Operators/VariantCasts.hpp:16:35:   required from 'ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantCasts<TImpl>::operator T() const [with T = const void*; TImpl = ArduinoJson6120_000001::MemberProxy<ArduinoJson6120_000001::JsonDocument&, const char*>]'

C:\Users\error404\source\repos\IOT\esp32\esp32.ino:70:47:   required from here

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantAs.hpp:61:61: note: candidate: template<class T> typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::enable_if<ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, bool>::value, T>::type ArduinoJson6120_000001::variantAs(const ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantData*)

 inline typename enable_if<is_same<T, bool>::value, T>::type variantAs(

                                                             ^

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantAs.hpp:61:61: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantAs.hpp: In substitution of 'template<class T> typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::enable_if<ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, bool>::value, T>::type ArduinoJson6120_000001::variantAs(const ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantData*) [with T = const void*]':

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantRef.hpp:240:24:   required from 'typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::enable_if<(((! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ArrayRef>::value) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ObjectRef>::value)) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantRef>::value)), typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantAs<T>::type>::type ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantRef::as() const [with T = const void*; typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::enable_if<(((! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ArrayRef>::value) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ObjectRef>::value)) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantRef>::value)), typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantAs<T>::type>::type = const void*]'

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Object/MemberProxy.hpp:70:52:   required from 'typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantAs<T>::type ArduinoJson6120_000001::MemberProxy<TParent, TStringRef>::as() const [with TValue = const void*; TObject = ArduinoJson6120_000001::JsonDocument&; TStringRef = const char*; typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantAs<T>::type = const void*]'

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Operators/VariantCasts.hpp:16:35:   required from 'ArduinoJson6120_000001::VariantCasts<TImpl>::operator T() const [with T = const void*; TImpl = ArduinoJson6120_000001::MemberProxy<ArduinoJson6120_000001::JsonDocument&, const char*>]'

C:\Users\error404\source\repos\IOT\esp32\esp32.ino:70:47:   required from here

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantAs.hpp:61:61: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct ArduinoJson6120_000001::enable_if<false, const void*>'

C:\Users\error404\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantRef.hpp: In instantiation of 'typename ArduinoJson6120_000001::enable_if<(((! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ArrayRef>::value) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, ArduinoJson6120_000001::ObjectRef>::value)) && (! ArduinoJson6120_000001::is_same<T, 

exit status 1
Fehler beim Kompilieren für das Board ESP32 Dev Module.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its own way, the compiler tries to say "I don't know how to convert `doc["Pin"]` to a `const void*`".

Indeed, ArduinoJson doesn't support conversion to `const void*`; it supports conversion to `const char*`, but that doesn't make sense here. Instead, you want to convert `doc["Pin"]` to an integer and assign it to the variable passed by the caller of `DeserializeJson()`.

The solution is to use the assignment operator instead of `memcpy()`:

```cpp
*pin = doc["Pin"];
*pinmode = doc['Mode"];
*timeInMilliseconds = doc["TimeInMilliseconds"];
```

Comment: It works. Thank you for the explanation!!! You really saved my day! :)